# Is there a rule that allows me to fuse 2 NPCs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, npc, rise-of-the-runelords

I'm running *Rise of the Runelords* and, throughout the encounters, several major foes managed to run away. Specifically, Nualia Tobyn (an Aasimar Cleric 4/Fighter 2) and Lucrecia (a Lamia Matriarch).

They fled to seek assistance, and I would like for them to face my adventuring group again to show my party the dreadful power of Mokmurian.

Of course, I could just say that Mokmurian makes it happen somehow, but if there are any published rules on forcibly merging/melding/fusing two unwilling creatures I would like to know about them.

I wanted to merge them because:

- As they are now, they are not a threat to the party.
- They fled with a lot of injury so it could have been a way for Mokmurian to save them, to make a powerfull creature and to punish them at the same time.
- The players liked all the horror that their characters faced.

So it will be interesting for my adventuring group to face known foes with new power and maybe parts roughly stitched together.

Comment: What mechanics are you looking for here? Are you saying that you had two bosses run away and you want them to fight the party again, but to make them more powerful, you want them to physically fuse together into one creature? If not, please explain further what you want to happen here.

Comment: There are 3rd party templates to achieve this.

Comment: Regardless, that alone shouldnt be the reason to reopen if it was closed because it was "unclear". Even if there was no way to obtain this, the proper answer would simply say "Nope". He should offer more information as to why he wants to merge two npcs instead of simply bringing them back to the fight, and what purpose he is attempting to achieve with this (cause horror, for instance?).

Comment: I don't see how this is unclear. I understand what it is OP wants on my first read of the question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The third-party Amalgam monster template consists of two fused creatures.

Unlike other monster templates that are applied to single creatures, the [Amalgam template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/amalgam-creature-cr-special) applies to two creatures, and results in one. It has a combination of both creatures' strengths and weaknesses. The Amalgam rules are complicated and awkward, and don't synergize well when the component creatures have class levels or different types of spellcasting. Note that the template doesn't specify how an NPC would perform the fusion.

If you apply this template to Nualia and Lucrecia, you may have to adjust its stats.

There is also the [Dichotomous](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/dichotomous-creature-cr-1) template, which fuses two outsiders, but Lucrecia is a monstrous humanoid.

#### Fusing enemy NPCs often results in a weaker encounter.

One creature, with the combined stats of two creatures, is generally a weaker fight than the two creatures separately. This is because action economy is valuable, if not the most valuable resource in the game. As a fused creature, they have one turn per round. They could easily be surrounded or flanked, and one unlucky saving throw against a PC's spell could negate their offensive power, if not take them out of fight entirely.

In contrast, if they attacked as a team, they would have two turns per round. Two spells, or two full-round attacks, or one of each. They can also use flank tactics, assist each other, or target different PCs.

#### What does the lore say?

Mokmurian is evil, but he probably wouldn't try to fuse them into some awkward hybrid. If Nualia and Lucrecia approached him with the intent of getting his help, he would probably

> try to assist or recruit them, because he wants to build an army.

You could also modify their stats (such as applying the [Advanced](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/advanced-creature-cr-1) template, extra levels, or buffs with [*permanency*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency)) or equipment to make them more powerful, because

> Mokmurian is a wealthy and powerful [transmuter](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Mokmurian), with a library of ancient Thassilonian knowledge, and can craft [magic rings](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/forge-ring-item-creation) or [scrolls of 7th level wizard spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/scribe-scroll-item-creation) with caster level 14

With those sort of resources, a Nualia + Lucrecia teamup revenge fight could pose a real challenge to the PCs. Note that the *Rise of the Runelords* adventure path already suggests what these NPCs would do if they survive against the PCs.